# php called python script

Tags: php, python, file-io, fwrite

I've got a problem with a python script. The script itself generates a string and writes it at the end to a file. This works well when I call the python script directly.

But as soon as I call the python script from PHP with exec(), it can't write to the file anymore.

In python I simply use:

```
try:
    FILE = open(filename,"w")
    FILE.write(mystring)
except IOError:
    print 'cannot open', filename
```

and PHP calls the python script like this:

```
$command = 'python myscript.py input1 input2 > /dev/null &';
exec($command, $stdout, $error);
```

Does anyone know what to do solve the problem?

Comment: Maybe the process running your PHP script has different permissions than your local user?

Comment: Are the permissions for the PHP process set properly?

Comment: Have you tried setting the permissions on your destination file so that it is open and world writeable?

Comment: do you close your file after writing?. Use with context manager

Comment: are you sure the command is running?  consider the `system` or `passthru` functions that allow you to get return code or program output.

Comment: @larsmans: thanks for the hint. it has been the read/write permission. i set the file to 777 and now its working properly.

Answer (score 1):

*it can't write to the file*

What error message are you getting?
I notice that you are reporting an error in the Python script using a straight print to stdout, and redirecting stdout to /dev/null when running. The stderror string is a useful part of an IOError exception.
You could change your `except` to something like this:

```
except IOError, err:
    sys.stderr.write("Could not open "+ err.filename + ": " + err.strerror + "\n")
```

or you could use stdout and redirect the output to a real file instead of /dev/null - at least until you have nailed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is `filename` a relative or absolute path? I would recommend using absolute paths so your script will work however it's called - for example `"/home/matt/scripts/python/test.txt"` is an absolute path.

This is a common error with scripts called by other scripts, or called by system events or cronjobs, etc.

Hope that helps

Comment: i tried it with relative and absolute path. both did not work. :(

Answer (score 0):

There is a system-function which you can find in PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php

```
$var = system('python sample.py myargs', $ref);
```